# How to export my OMNeT++ model as an FMU( Functional Mockup Unit)?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, fmi, pyfmi

I am trying to co-simulate **MATLAB and OMNeT++**. For the co-simulation interface, I am using Ptolemy-VirGIL to connect the two models as FMUs. MATLAB export is quite easy but I cannot find a way to export my OMNeT++ model as an FMU. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMNet++ does not offer export as FMU.

Export as FMU is neither mentioned in the [OmNet++ Documentation](https://omnetpp.org/documentation/) nor does the [OMNeT++ source code](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/) contain any meaningful mentions of [FMU](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/search?q=repo%3Aomnetpp%2Fomnetpp+fmu) or [FMI](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/search?q=repo%3Aomnetpp%2Fomnetpp+fmi).

You can create your own wrapper or find someone who does it for you. Start out with a simple *ModelExchange* example from the [FMU SDK](https://www.qtronic.de/en/fmu-sdk/), and put your OMNet++ model in there.

The SDK is a little extensive, in principal the only files that need to be adapted are (illustrated with the bouncingBall example):

1. ./fmu20/src/models/bouncingBall/modelDescription_me.xml
2. ./fmu20/src/models/bouncingBall/bouncingBall.c

In the XML file, you define your model's interface. The C file needs to be adapted to contain/call your OMNet++ model.

Comment: I tried it but it is proving to b very difficult. Firstly to install VS 2015(older version which isn't directly available) for building FMU SDK files and then the Virtual Studio won't set up the environment variables, which are important for the batch files to make FMUs and simulators(for example, install.bat).

Any suggestions??